# Neither do I / Nor do I / Me neither / Me either

Tags: expressions

In this circumstance, which would be the most correct / natural answer?

> Person 1: I don't eat meat
>   Person 2: Neither do I / Nor do I / Me neither / Me either

[This](//english.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/is-me-neither-incorrect) says both "neither do I" and "Me neither" are often used. But I have also heard / read "me either" and "nor do I" in multiple scenarios. Which then is the correct way of saying it? Are the others wrong or just not used?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's not a matter of *"correct"*-ness. It's a matter of social class and personal presentation.

In decreasing order of falutation:

1. *nor do I* (archaic; now either ironic or intended to sound classy, or both)
2. *neither do I* (normal in writing, common in speech)
3. *me either* (common in speech, more familiar)
4. *me neither* (common in ingroup speech)

... roughly speaking, of course; I'm no sociolinguist.

This kind of social layering for language variation is completely normal, in every language. To call one mode *"correct"* would be wrong; appropriateness of speech or writing depends on the speaker/writer's aims, and their judgement of their relationship with their listener/reader (and of course on how accurate their judgement is). What's correct in one situation is often incorrect in another.

Comment: I guess it all comes down to the region of the world you are in. I remember reading somewhere that "me either" is more common in the UK and Australia, whereas the US uses "neither do I" or "me neither" more commonly.

Comment: Wonder what to make of *me either* (common in speech, more familiar) -- technically incorrect, incomprehensibly oxymoronic for anyone unfamiliar with the 'usage', inconvenient to pronounce and not so pleasant to hear.

Comment: @Kris: Which is why I prefer to say _me neither_ when possible. My favorite, when I can get away with it, is Spanish _tampoco yo_, which is unambiguous, and mellifluous in my opinion.

Comment: I don't recognise _me either_ and would count it as ungrammatical. On the other hand, _nor do I_ is absolutely normal for me, and doesn't sound either classy or archaic. I probably say it more readily than _neither do I_.

Comment: I agree with @Colin about _nor do I_: it's prefectly commonplace, even colloquially, in BrE. I don't agree with him about _me either_, though, which is quite common as well, even in BrE (though perhaps it's a more recent loan from AmE and more restricted to younger speakers?). I'd be unlikely to say it myself, but I hear it frequently enough).

Comment: FWIW, I can't find a reasonable definition for "falutation" anywhere, including on this site!

Comment: When I consider that *"I do too"* or *"I would too"* can be substituted with *"me too"*, I feel like it's *not unnatural* to substitute *"I don't either"* or *"I wouldn't either"* with *"me either"*. They feel more like a set if neither of them change form when following *"me"*. However, when I consider that *"me either"* is missing the part that makes it negative, I have to conclude that *"me neither"* is more correct. After all, isn't *"neither"* [a sort of contraction of *"not either"*](https://www.etymonline.com/word/neither)? *"Me either"* implies the negative part while omitting it.

Comment: I've never heard **falutation** before.

Comment: **Falutation.**  High, low or middle!  What a great day for innovatin’. Love it.

Comment: @Mentalist: "This man does not like dogs, and that one (doesn't) EITHER, and ME EITHER". As you said "Me either and Me too" are there for a reason. It is not a "mistake". "Me either" agrees with a negative statement, and as such CANNOT have the second negation (me Neither). "Me neither" does "feel nice" triggering some switch in the brain yearning to say "Not either". The reality and logic here are bulletproof. ME EITHER is the only correct way. How can so many "experts" be so blind? Habits are hard to break I guess.

Answer (score 13):

**Neither do I** and **Me neither** are both correct responses to **I don't eat meat**. So is **Nor do I**. So is **I don't either**. But **Me either** is incorrect. Also note that **Me neither** is informal (mainly because of the **Me** part rather than the **neither** part).

Comment: Not forgetting the jokey 'Me too neither'.

Comment: Agreed, with the note that "Nor do I" (or **Nor I**) would sound very formal in spoken conversation, at least to my ears.

Comment: *Me either* is fine in some dialects – it's quite common in American English –  although like *me neither* it's informal.  It's safer for learners to stick to *me neither*, though, because in many dialects *me either* simply doesn't work.

Comment: @Snailplane: Me either is the only correct option across all dialects. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FNWiKe3Foo&ab_channel=MitCherny

Answer (score 4):

"neither" and "nor" and "don't either" etc are for use in response to a negative. ("I DON'T eat meat")

"either", unless directly preceded by "don't" or some other negative, refers to alternatives, such as "You either eat meat or you don't."

Strictly speaking "I" is used when the speaker is the subject ( you wouldn't say "me don't eat meat")

"me neither", strictly speaking, is short for "me also don't", which has "me" as the subject. However, hardly anyone says "I neither" and "Me neither" has come to be acceptable. "Nor me" is still less acceptable than "Nor I" in this context.

"Me neither" or "Nor me." would be a response to the speaker being the object, such as when the initial statement has the form "Dogs don't bite me."

"I don't bite dogs."  could be answered by  "Nor I."

"Dogs don't bite me." could be answered by  "Nor me."

In response to "Don't bite me!" Be careful not to say "Gnaw me!"

Comment: Upvoted just for the terrible pun at the end.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a sentence like "I don't eat meat" the two correct answers are:
1) Neither do I (or)
2) I don't either.

Comment: Hi Ephren, welcome to EL&U. Could you elaborate on your answer? It's always helpful to explain your reasoning and possibly provide sources.

Comment: Why do you think that there are only two correct answers?  And why the two that you give in particular?

Answer (score 0):

To make it plain, Ephren gave a good sum up of the question.
However, despite the right observation from Armen concerning the "Me" part in "Me neither", we use in US :
Me either ; Me neither ; Nor do I.
Neither do I seems more precious.
I also hear "Neither I"

An other question would be the reply concerning : "she doesn't like me".
"Me neither" could mean that "I also don't like you" like "nor do I" or "Neither do I"
But "She doesn't like me, either/neither" would be exact & "me either" is  common speaking to understand : she doesn't like (neither) you nor me.

NB : "Me either/neither" are only OK for familiar speech.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FNWiKe3Foo&ab_channel=MitCherny The answer as to why "Me neither" does not make any sense.

Answer (score -2):

**"ME EITHER" IS THE ONLY CORRECT VERSION.**

"Me neither" contains (**N**either) which is the **second negative** to an **already negative** statement you are agreeing with, which is impossible under the rules of sound English grammar.

Perhaps this piece of logic will convince the "Me Neither" heretics.

1. Me too = I (do) too = So do I.
2. Me EITHER = I (don't) either = Neither do I.
3. **Me Neither** = **I (don't) neither** = **grammatical heresy**.

(I might be "wrong", of course, as there is a "song" titled : *I **wouldn't** love me **neither**).
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GQ2HIpuS6Y4&ab_channel=VEKProduction

Even if we supposed that **Me Neither = I (do) neither**. "I do Neither" is grammatically correct, but alas, the meaning has nothing to do with agreeing with a statement: **Do you smoke or drink? I do neither**...**Nothing to do with "Me Neither".**

This man does not like cats, and **that one...EITHER**, and **ME EITHER**.

**THE ONLY CORRECT VERSION IS ME EITHER**.

Comment: And what *are* the “rules of sound English grammar”?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you, if you don't know nothing about no multiple negatives.