# neither do I, me neither/either

Tags: grammar

I was trying to understand which one to use. If someone says "I don't like you" Should I say "me neither", "neither do I" or "me either"?

If she says "I hate you", what will be the difference and why?

Comment: Try this answer: [_Neither do I / Nor do I / Me neither / Me either_](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/56776/15299).

Comment: 'Me either' makes no sense.

Comment: All your suggestions mean "I also do not like myself."

Answer (score 1):

Are you intending to tell this person that you don't like *yourself*? If so, it's 'Neither do I' or, more informally, 'Me neither."

If you mean that you don't like *her,* you would have to say 'I don't like *you* either'.

*Either* and *neither* are only used after a negative statement, so the response to 'I hate you' is 'I hate myself/you too'.

Comment: *"So the response to 'I hate you' is 'I hate myself/you too'."*  Or "So do I." (=I hate myself too)

Comment: Well, yes, if that is indeed the OP's meaning.